# Is it possible to integrate svn from different host?

Tags: svn, web-hosting

I have a web account, which host my current website/project at XXX hosting company, but with very few privileges.  And I signup for a free svn hosting at YYY company. Issit possible to integrate my projects files from 2 different hosts?

For examples, I update my files to the svn at YYY, then it will update the files automatically to my website at XXX? If the answer is yes, please kindly guide me, or advise me how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your central repository will be YYYY. You can commit changes to YYYY repository from anywhere you've done a `svn checkout`.

From anywhere, commit your changes to YYYY using :

```
svn com -m "commit message"
```

From XXX, if you've have done an initial svn checkout, you could then synchronize your files by calling :

```
svn update
```

But I would not recommend synchronizing a local copy of a SVN repository on a production server. Instead, I would 'svn export' somewhere on a test platform or on your desktop, and push files to the production server using sftp.

Comment: Nice!! So, I have to setup 2 svns, 1 at YYY and 1 at XXX? How do I link them?

Comment: As you said, "free svn hosting at YYY". On YYY service user interface, create a new SVN repository. Check the URL of this new repository. On XXXX, do a : svn checkout https://XXXX/path/to/the/repo  or something like that. Check SVN manual for more info : http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your files ay YYYY and then periodically update the files checked out from YYYY at XXXX. You can do the update manually or via cron periodically.

Comment: Hey stone, thanks for the answer. Hmm, I see, but I am worry it would be confusing of what files to upload to XXX in future. I am using cakephp, which has a lot of files, how do I know which files have been updated? Could you please explain the cron job thing? Do you mean, upload the entire website folder?

Comment: You have your svn on YYYY. You check it out to XXXX, the entire svn. Then you put files into your YYYY svn what you want on XXXX. The cron job should be just "cd /your/dir/; svn update" that's all.